# ¿Cómo comparar dos arrays y eliminar los objetos que sean iguales y retornar solo los que no se encuentren en uno de ellos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Justo como se hace en `php` ([enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php)) pero quisiera hacerlo en `javascript`.

```js
var data1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "No Se"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Etiquetado"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

console.log(data1);

var data2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

console.log(data2);
```

**Actualización 1:**
Que de esos 2 `arrays` me retorne el siguiente:

```js
var data3 = [{
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "No Se"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Etiquetado"
  }
];

console.log(data3);
```

Comment: Primero que todo quiero aclarar que esas variables no son `JSON` son dos `arrays` (arreglos) con objetos por elementos

Comment: Existe (o existía porque ahora mismo no la encuentro) una pregunta similar en SOes, ¿es esto parte de una tarea escolar? ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿podrías añadir una mejor descripción para "_retornar solo los que no se encuentren en uno de ellos_"?

Comment: @Jorius ok gracias por la aclaratoria

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no hermano, es trabajo y ya edito la pregunta.

Comment: Deben coincidir tanto en id y nombre????

Comment: Ok. Recuerdo que la otra pregunta era muy confusa porque no se aclaraba si tenía que coincidir id o nombre o los dos, o si el orden era importante, etc. Sería bueno que añadieras esa información.

Comment: @PabloContreras, en la web de `Locutus`, puede encontrar todas las funciones `PHP` implementadas en `JS`, como por ejemplo [`array_diff_assoc`](http://locutus.io/php/array/array_diff_assoc/)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo también iba a comentarle esa página, jaja

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si deben coincidir cada uno de los objetos, exactamente, que contiene el array. aunque el `id` viene de la `db` asociado con el nombre, si el `id` coincide es porque es igual.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ok bro, voy a revisarlo.

Comment: @Jorius de igual manera gracias :D

Comment: @MarcosGallardo se puede instalar en mi sistema que no sea por `npm`? no existe el `.js` que se simplemente se llame el archivo? no he usado `npm` hasta los momentos, por eso lo pregunto.

Comment: Esto no es lo mismo que `array_diff_assoc`. No estás comparandos dos objetos sino dos arrays que contienen objetos.

Comment: @amenadiel ok, gracias por aclararlo, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Otra pregunta: qué pasa si el segundo array tiene un objeto que no está en el primero? también va en el resultado? O sólo quieres, estrictamente, los que estén en el primero y no en el segundo

Comment: Solo quiero, estrictamente, los que están en el primero y no los del segundo. Por que el primero es el que tendrá el caso de tener objetos demás que el segundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto evidentemente se puede hacer con javascript puro pero, para trabajar con colecciones, ya hay herramientas archiprobadas como underscore y [lodash](https://lodash.com).

La siguiente solución utiliza el método [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) de lodash.

```js
var data1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "No Se"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Etiquetado"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];


var data2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

var data3=[];

_.each(data1,function(objeto) {
  
  var elemento_en_data2 = _.find(data2,objeto);
  
  if(elemento_en_data2===undefined) {
    data3.push(objeto);
  }
  
});

console.log(data3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

La principal dificultad de tu pregunta es que en javascript dos objetos no son iguales entre sí aunque tengan las mismas propiedades. Por lo mismo buscar la existencia de un determinado objeto usando el método `indexOf`

```
var posicion = data2.indexOf({"id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion"});
```

Siempre dirá que el objeto no está en el array. Habría que implementar una función de igualdad que se cumpla cuando las propiedades enumerables de dos objetos coincidan, y luego recorrer en bucles anidados ambos arrays comprobando si hay elemento que cumplan con esa función custom. Prefiero no reinventar la rueda.

Comment: "Prefiero no reinventar la rueda." jaja.. muy buen comentario. Gracias hermano. Hace justo lo que necesito.

Answer (score 6):

No sé si esta sea la forma que buscas pero la añado ya que llega al resultado esperado. recorrer los dos array con dos `For` simples. luego ir comparando las diferencias entre los campos .

```js
var data1 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 6, "nombre": "No Se" },
  { "id": 5, "nombre": "Etiquetado" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

var data2 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    var igual=false;
     for (var j = 0; j < data2.length & !igual; j++) {
         if(data1[i]['id'] == data2[j]['id'] && 
            data1[i]['nombre'] == data2[j]['nombre']) 
                 igual=true;
     }
    if(!igual)array.push(data1[i]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: gracias hermano

Answer (score 2):

Aquí dejo una versión en JavaScript puro, aunque es un poco "fea". La idea es convertir los objetos a cadenas, para que sean más fáciles de trabajar. Y los pasos serían:

1. Convertimos los arrays de objetos a arrays de cadenas
2. Añadimos todas las cadenas del primer array que no estén en el segundo
3. Añadimos todas las cadenas del segundo array que no estén en el primero
4. Convertimos las cadenas de nuevo a objetos

El código quedaría así:

```js
var data1 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 6, "nombre": "No Se" },
  { "id": 5, "nombre": "Etiquetado" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

var data2 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

// convertimos los arrays de objetos a arrays de cadenas
var aux1 = data1.map(function(el) { return JSON.stringify(el); });
var aux2 = data2.map(function(el) { return JSON.stringify(el); });

// añadimos todas las cadenas del primer array que no estén en el segundo
var data3 = aux1.filter(function(el) {
  if (aux2.indexOf(el) < 0) return el;
});

// añadimos todas las cadenas del segundo array que no estén en el primero
data3 = data3.concat( aux2.filter(function(el) {
  if (aux1.indexOf(el) < 0) return el;
}));

// convertimos las cadenas de nuevo a objetos
data3 = data3.map(function (el) { return JSON.parse(el); });

// mostramos el resultado
console.log(data3);
```

---

Si no quieres convertir objetos a cadenas, puedes definir tu propia función de comparación y atravesar los arrays buscando elementos duplicados (en lugar de usar `indexOf`).

Algo como esto:

```js
var data1 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 6, "nombre": "No Se" },
  { "id": 5, "nombre": "Etiquetado" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

var data2 = [
  { "id": 1, "nombre": "Mezcla" },
  { "id": 4, "nombre": "Vaciado" },
  { "id": 3, "nombre": "Llenado" },
  { "id": 2, "nombre": "Esterilizacion" }
];

// añadimos todas las cadenas del primer array que no estén en el segundo
var data3 = data1.filter(function(el) {
  var found = false, x = 0;
  while (x < data2.length && !found) {
    if (el.id == data2[x].id && el.nombre == data2[x].nombre) found = true;
    x++;
  }
  if (!found) return el;
});

// añadimos todas las cadenas del segundo array que no estén en el primero
data3 = data3.concat( data2.filter(function(el) {
  var found = false, x = 0;
  while (x < data1.length && !found) {
    if (el.id == data1[x].id && el.nombre == data1[x].nombre) found = true;
    x++;
  }
  if (!found) return el;
}));

console.log(data3);
```

Comment: gracias, como siempre un código bien explicado.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí mi versión de `array_diff_assoc` la cual:

- Soporta `1 o más` arreglos
- Compara los objetos usando `JSON.stringify`
- Devuelve todos los valores de `arr1` que **no están en todo los demas**.

Demo:

```js
function array_diff_assoc () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
   arr = args.shift().splice(0);

  args.forEach(function(arrN) {
    arrN.forEach(function(objN) {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]) === JSON.stringify(objN)) {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  
  return arr;
}

var data1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "No Se"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Etiquetado"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

var data2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

console.log(array_diff_assoc(data1, data2));
```

Comment: interesante solución, propia y sencilla. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**Basado en tú pregunta he asumido que los objetos siempre van a ser simples, sin métodos ni nodos html, de lo contrario la solución sería un poco más compleja**

```
Array.prototype.arrayDiffAssoc = function(){
            //Une los arrays
    return [].concat.apply( this, arguments )
                //Convierte a string los json (funciona siempre que sea un objeto simple)
                .map(function(obj){ return JSON.stringify(obj) })
                //remueve los elementos duplicados que van a retornar siempre lenght > 1
                .filter(function(item, index, self) { return self.filter(function(duplicate){ return item === duplicate; }).length === 1; })
                //restaura los objetos en el array
                .map(function(obj) { return JSON.parse(obj); });
}

//Te permite
data1.arrayDiffAssoc(data2); // [{"id": 6,"nombre": "No Se"},{"id": 5, "nombre": "Etiquetado"}]

//o en caso de tener otro array para comparar
data1.arrayDiffAssoc(data2, data3); // [{"id": 6,"nombre": "No Se"},{"id": 5, "nombre": "Etiquetado"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi version para esta pregunta

```
var data1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "No Se"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Etiquetado"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

var data2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Mezcla"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Vaciado"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Llenado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Esterilizacion"
  }
];

    var data3=[];
        data1.forEach(i => {
        var existe= false;
        data2.forEach(j => {
          !igual && i.id== j.id&& (existe= true);
        });
        !existe && data3.push(i);
      });

console.log(data3);
```

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas. Trata de dar detalles de cómo tu propuesta resuelve la duda del OP.