# Eliminar elemento de array a partir de otro array según su valor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Deseo eliminar elementos de un array según su valor a partir de otro array**
**. He estado tratando de la siguiente manera pero no logro conseguirlo**

```js
const concept = [
  { "n_docu": "23248169", "c_prod": "000004", "l_prod": "FAENAS" },
  { "n_docu": "46117631", "c_prod": "000005", "l_prod": "MULTAS" }
];

const datos = [
  { "n_docu": "23248169", "l_agen": "USUARIO", "FAENAS": "1.00", "MULTAS": "0.00" },
  { "n_docu": "71377558", "l_agen": "SIMEON", "FAENAS": "5.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" },
  { "n_docu": "46117631", "l_agen": "EGUAVIL", "FAENAS": "0.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" }
];

const resp = [];

concept.forEach((c, index) =>
  resp.push(datos.filter(m => c.n_docu !== m.n_docu))
);

console.log(resp);
```

**La respuesta que deseo obtener:**

```json
[
  {
    "n_docu": "71377558",
    "l_agen": "SIMEON",
    "FAENAS": "5.00",
    "MULTAS": "1.00"
  }
]
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario usar `.filter` en este caso? Porque si no hay varias formas distintas de hacerlo sin usarlo, como se explica en las respuestas a esta pregunta:  [¿Cómo comparar dos arrays y eliminar los objetos que sean iguales y retornar solo los que no se encuentren en uno de ellos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58926/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-dos-arrays-y-eliminar-los-objetos-que-sean-iguales-y-retornar-sol).

Comment: Hola, Freddy. Allí tiene dos opciones de respuesta. Una que elimina los elementos del _array_ mediante la utilización del método `splice` a partir de la propiedad `n_docu` y la otra propuesta por @Japsz que los filtra mediante el método  `filter` devolviendo una copia.

Comment: gracias @DavidE.LunaM. , '@Japsz', justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 2):

> No olvide leer los comentarios que se encuentran en el código. Le será de mucha ayuda.

### Solo se tiene que identificar el índice

Sé que encontrar el índice en un *array* de objetos puede parecer algo tedioso. Sin embargo, el primer paso es encontrarlo y luego con ello eliminar del *array* los elementos a partir del otro [*array*].

Solo tiene que utilizar dos bucles, uno anidado en otro:

```js
concept.forEach(item => {
    for ( index in datos ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Justo allí (donde van los puntos suspensivos `...` en el ejemplo anterior) compararemos la propiedad `n_docu` de cada objeto en ambos *arrays* de objetos, es decir:

```js
if (datos[index].n_docu == item.n_docu) {
    ...
}
```

Y finalmente, eliminamos los elementos del *array* utilizando el método [**`splice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
datos.splice(index, 1);
```

Donde `index` es el ìndice del *array* `datos` y `1` la cantidad de elementos a eliminar a partir de `index`.

#### Implementación completa

Ya que se tiene claro lo anteriormente expuesto veamos un ejemplo completo de cómo funciona:

```js
const concept = [
  { n_docu: "23248169", c_prod: "000004", l_prod: "FAENAS" },
  { n_docu: "46117631", c_prod: "000005", l_prod: "MULTAS" }
];

const datos = [
  { n_docu: "23248169", l_agen: "USUARIO", FAENAS: "1.00", MULTAS: "0.00" },
  { n_docu: "71377558", l_agen: "SIMEON", FAENAS: "5.00", MULTAS: "1.00" },
  { n_docu: "46117631", l_agen: "EGUAVIL",  FAENAS: "0.00", MULTAS: "1.00" }
];

concept.forEach((item) => {
  for (let index in datos) {
    // Si el índice de ambos array coinciden se procederá
    // a eliminar el elemento de «datos»:
    if (datos[index].n_docu == item.n_docu) {
      datos.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

// Mostrar resultados:
console.log( datos );
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más cómodo a mi idea es usar `.filter()` y el método de *arrays* `.includes()`. Para tu problema, solo necesitas generar un *arreglo* que tenga solo los *ids* que quieres **filtrar** para luego recorrer el otro usando `.filter()`.

```js
const concept = [
  { "n_docu": "23248169", "c_prod": "000004", "l_prod": "FAENAS" },
  { "n_docu": "46117631", "c_prod": "000005", "l_prod": "MULTAS" }
];

const datos = [
  { "n_docu": "23248169", "l_agen": "USUARIO", "FAENAS": "1.00", "MULTAS": "0.00" },
  { "n_docu": "71377558", "l_agen": "SIMEON", "FAENAS": "5.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" },
  { "n_docu": "46117631", "l_agen": "EGUAVIL", "FAENAS": "0.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" }
];

// Arreglo con Ids a filtrar
const idsNoPermitidos = concept.map(doc => doc.n_docu);

// Sólo aceptar aquellos que n_docu no esté en el arreglo de idsNoPermitidos
const datosFiltrados = datos.filter(doc => !idsNoPermitidos.includes(doc.n_docu))

console.log(datosFiltrados)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me funciona bastante bien este ejemplo con reduce, para comparar los valores de un atributo.

```
const datos = [
 { "n_docu": "23248169", "l_agen": "USUARIO", "FAENAS": "1.00", "MULTAS": "0.00" },
 { "n_docu": "71377558", "l_agen": "SIMEON", "FAENAS": "5.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" },
 { "n_docu": "46117631", "l_agen": "EGUAVIL", "FAENAS": "0.00", "MULTAS": "1.00" }
];

 datos.reduce((accArr, value) => {
  if (accArr.filter(elm => elm.MULTAS == value.MULTAS).length == 0) {
   accArr.push(value);
  }
  return accArr;
 }, [])
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).